# awk floating point comparison not working

Tags: awk, floating-point

I have input file with with x1 , x2 and x values, I want to check if x is midpoint between x1 and x2.
But the comparison is failing.

sample input file

```
x1=20.9280 x2=20.9600 x=20.9440
x1=20.9280 x2=20.9600 x=20.9440
x1=22.7840 x2=22.8160 x=22.8000
```

Awk command

```
awk -F'[ =]' '{ if(($2 + $4)/2 != ($6)) print ($2 + $4)/2, " ", $6;}' sample
```

OUTPUT

```
20.944   20.9440
20.944   20.9440
22.8   22.8000
```

Comparison is failing due to extra zeros after decimal points. Please help to fix it.

Comment: you could remove `0` at the end of `$6` with `sub(/0+$/, "", $6)` before performing your comparisons.. but in general, comparing floats directly is risky, typically absolute difference between the two floats is checked against a small value, like `0.00001`

Comment: @EdMorton I think OP wanted to print cases where the last column doesn't match midpoint calculation, for example `x1=20.9280 x2=20.9600 x=20.9240` (changed example) .. but with the code posted in question, all three lines were printed even though all of them have correct midpoint in final column.. that's why OP says they expected no output for example lines posted in question...

Comment: @EdMorton so, OP is probably just looking for `awk -F'[ =]' '{gsub(/\./,"")} ($6*2) != ($2+$4)'`

Comment: @Sundeep thanks, I'm an idiot, I missed the `!` in the comparison. And yes, that conversion is what I put in my answer.

Comment: well, I copied it from your answer ;) nice trick btw!

Comment: I think you should have a look at this page: https://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/ . When you compare floating point numbers, you should not check if they are the same, you should check if the relative difference is really really small! Using `printf` or `sprintf` statement will work **if and only if** you use the `%e` format specifier. This allows you to define a relative difference. Eg. `%e25.7` will create a number that looks like `____________sn.fffffffesxx` where `s` is a sign, `n,f,x` are digits. This allows you to compare numbers with a relative difference of `10^-8`

Comment: @kvantour thanks for the information . When I code in C++/C , I take their difference and check if its less than  epsilon. I was not aware of awk working. I coverted all them to string with %0.4f format and everything worked after that.

Comment: Even in C or C++ you should not compare differences, but relative differences. And again using `%0.4f` is a failure waiting to happen. Better to use `%25.7e`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening due to floating point comparison issue commonly found in all platforms.

You may use this `awk` for floating point number comparison by converting number to a floating point with 4 decimal points:

```
awk -F'[ =]+' '{avg = sprintf("%.4f", ($2 + $4) / 2)} avg != $6 { print avg, $6 }' file
```

---

If you have `gnu awk` then you can set precision to a lower number:

```
awk -M -v PREC=30 -F'[ =]+' '{avg = ($2 + $4) / 2; $6 += 0} avg != $6 { print avg, $6 }' file
```

Comment: I do not say this often, but I strongly discourage the first solution. Due to the `sprintf` statment you will create false positives. For example, all numbers between 1.23445 and 1.23455 will be converted to 1.2345.

Comment: Yes, I understand your point. `sprintf` solution is only for **non-gnu awk** and it is **customized** for OP's input that is using scale of 4 in all the numbers, so obviously case `1.23445` and `1.23455` doesn't exist here.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an anwser but do demonstrate. You are comparing floating point numbers, they are not equal. I replaced `print` with `printf` and modifiers with enough decimals (20, `%.20f`):

```
$ awk -F'[ =]' '{
    if(($2 + $4)/2 != ($6)) 
        printf "%.20f %.20f\n", ($2 + $4)/2, $6
}' file
```

Ottput:

```
20.94400000000000261480 20.94399999999999906208
20.94400000000000261480 20.94399999999999906208
22.79999999999999715783 22.80000000000000071054
```

So use `sprintf` and appropriate modifiers (see the `printf` I used) to control the values.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, if you are having a problem then it's probably that you're just tripping over the common floating point arithmetic issue but since all of your input values have the same precision you can just get rid of the `.`s to treat the input numbers as integers and multiply by 2 instead of dividing by 2 just to keep it an integer comparison too:

```
$ awk -F'[ =]' '{o=$0; gsub(/\./,"")} ($6*2) == ($2+$4){$0=o; print ($2+$4)/2, $6}' file
20.944 20.9440
20.944 20.9440
22.8 22.8000

$ awk -F'[ =]' '{o=$0; gsub(/\./,"")} ($6*2) != ($2+$4){$0=o; print ($2+$4)/2, $6}' file
$
```

Comment: I do not recommend to use this solution. It might work in the presented case, but what if the numbers start to take different "formats", "ranges", "proportions"

Comment: That's why it says `since all of your input values have the same precision`. It's only intended to be a simple solution for this particular case.